# Can't convert Bignum to string

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, migrate

I'm on a windows machine and I'm trying to make a scaffold with ruby's native powers, but I can't make this scaffold work, this is the command I'm using:

```
rails generate scaffold Page location_id:int title:varchar text:text type:int
```

I'm using mysql as the database engine and when I try to run "rake db:migrate" I'm getting the error: "Can't convert Bignum to string".

Can you guys please help me out.

Comment: is the error for the migration of Page model?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you need to use the correct Rails "types" in your scaffold such as integer and string:

```
rails generate scaffold Page location_id:integer title:string text:text type:integer
```

Comment: Thanks, that's right.. Stupid beginner mistake! Link to the Ruby on Rails guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#supported-types

Answer (score 0):

Received the answer on twitter:

> You don't need to use the mysql datatypes, but the ruby datatypes. varchar should be string, int should be integer

Stupid mistake, thanks for the answers guys!